# Riot JS still not rendering yielded tables properly

Tags: javascript, html, riot.js

I am currently writing a generic table component that provides some basic functionality to all tables I want to display on my site. Each actual table will then use this generic table and yield headers and content into the generic table.

With the - at the time of writing - latest version of Riot JS, there still appears to be a problem when yielding content into a table.
More specifically, when I yield into a table, Riot puts this information into the main tag (minus the `tr` and `td` tags) but keeps the actual table empty.

https://jsfiddle.net/ytgv5o5k/1/

Is there a fix coming up or a workaround that I can use right now? Some sources mention the `data-is` qualifier, but I don't see how to use this if I would like to re-use a generic table component.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a major pain point when using a framework that utilizes custom html tags. It actually has nothing to do with riot. What you're trying to do is not valid html, so the browser kicks the invalid tags out of the table.

See here: http://riotjs.com/guide/#riot-dom-caveats

If it makes sense in your application to break your table into separate tags, you should be able to handle it like this:

```
<table-container>
    <table>
        <tr data-is='table-row' each={ row in rows } row={ row }></tr>
    </table>
</table-container>
```

You won't be able to `yield` anything into a table that isn't valid html. As far as I know, riot has no concept of processing html before placing it in the DOM, which is when your tags will be moved out of the `table`. The only possibility of using `<yield/>` is to place content into cells

```
<td>
    <yield/>
</td>
```